# How can I get `fs::remove_dir_all` to remove a specific file upon test execution?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rocksdb

I am working on a project using Rust and RocksDB that creates a db log when certain tests are ran. Each time the tests are ran, the path gets created again and the information of both is saved. Eventually after so many tests, there would be a lot of unnecessary saved logs.

My goal was to use the function `std::fs::remove_dir_all` to remove the bd log file before each test is compiled so it would have a clean slate each time to create a brand new db log file.

```
#[test]
pub fn it_deletes() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    fs::remove_dir_all("relative path/.dblog")?;
    Ok(())
}
```

When I make a mock up test function shown above and run it, unfortunately it doesn't delete the file. But when I press Debug, next to the Test option (using vscode) it deletes the file successfully. Afterwards, in the Debug Console I get:

```
Console is in 'commands' mode, prefix expressions with '?'.
Launching: local debug path/it_deletes --exact --nocapture
Launched process 70701
Process exited with code 101.
```

Also, I get this error when trying to run cargo test.

```
---- it_deletes stdout ----
Error: Os { code: 2, kind: NotFound, message: "No such file or directory" }
```

I am a beginner with Rust, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: FYI `fs::remove_dir_all()` requires the path to be a directory. However, you'd get a separate "Not a directory" error, if that was the issue. The error says the `relative path/.dblog` does not exist. Double check if the path is correct. Additionally, tests like that can quickly backfire, since they might run out of order or in parallel with another test currently using that file

Comment: Print the working directory in both cases. May not be the case in Rust but I have seen in other systems (e.g. Dart) the working directory can be sometimes inconsistent depending on how you run the test.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given us a reproducible example, so it's not possible to answer the specific question you're asking conclusively. However, I do have a few general suggestions for debugging your tests.

1. Make use of a debugger. If you're using rust-analyzer through vscode then you should just be able to click the "Debug test" button above the test definition, if you don't have debugging set up, I believe vscode will auto-generate the config for you (it's possible you may have to install another extension, perhaps the lldb extension). Then you can set breakpoints and inspect the state of your test during execution, including the entire callstack.
2. Throw in some `println!`s for things you want to check. When a test fails, `cargo test` will show you the stdout from that test, so you can see what you printed (running with the vscode testing setup should also show you that somewhere, but I'm not intimately familiar with the interface to tell you exactly where). What I'd check in this case is the working directory when running the test, and the directory path you're passing to `remove_dir_all`, so you can check they're sensible.
3. Feel free to liberally use `expect` (or `unwrap`) in your test code. If you panic exactly where the error happens, it will be easier to see exactly the source of the error (rather than having gone up through potentially a long chain of `Result`s). You can also run `RUST_BACKTRACE=1 cargo test` to get a full backtrace on your panics, which can help pinpointing things.
4. If your tests interact with the filesystem, give them a temporary directory to play with. There are crates like [tempfile](https://lib.rs/crates/tempfile) or [figment](https://docs.rs/figment/latest/figment/struct.Jail.html) to help you do exactly that. This means you're much less likely to clobber files you care about, and if you're auto-generating a temp directory (in some OS-managed temp directory, so it will get cleaned up eventually), you can just not delete it yourself to inspect the contents for debugging purposes after the fact.